# Animator Controller: Animation Completion Callback

Tags: c#, animation, 3d, unity-game-engine

I've seen some posts on the legacy system using Animations, but I'm using an Animator Controller and I want to know when an animation has completed playing.

Is there a way to assign a callback to when an animation has completed playing?

I could create a co-routine and check every frame but I feel thats the wrong way to do it.

Do you know how to check when an Animation Controller Animation has finished playing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Mecanim this will give you what you want:

```
 if(this.animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("AnimationName"))
 {
    // Do something.
 }
```

Make sure you use the correct *AnimationName* and you will be alright.

---

The API reference [GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo.html).

> Gets the current State information on a specified AnimatorController
>   layer.

It takes one parameter which is The Layer's Index.

---

#### Event Solution

You can trigger an Event by calling a function. You need to write the name of the function you want to call at the selected frame in the `Function` area of the `Edit Animation Event` window.

Short [tutorial](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/animeditor-AnimationEvents.html) on how to do it.

Comment: Yes, but this again requires me to check every frame. Something I'd like to avoid as unnecessary overhead!

Comment: I thought this was legacy I didn't think this worked with the current animator controller system

Comment: @Aggressor By the way, an if statement running on your `Update()` is relatively free processing time.

Comment: I will be working on this on the weekend. I will try out your method, if I get it working I'll post back :) My thanks